# MFC MDI CtabView hidden / remove navigation controls that are not used

Tags: c++, tabs, visual-studio-2017, mfc, clistview

I have 4 buttons that have no direct application to my program. I would like to hide or remove them. I've searched to find out what they are called...they look like navigation, left/right arrows, next/previous. I can't seem to find what they are called. I have looked on the Microsoft site and looking at the `CTabView` members doesn't seem to jump out and say "hey, these are what you're looking for"....

[image: Buttons I'd like to remove]

I'm hoping it is a relatively easy task. Anyone know how to just "turn them off"?

Thanks.

## UPDATE:

I was able to resolve the C4430 mentioned by moving the new function before the existing in `OutputWnd.h` and that solved the issue in the output pane area where the arrows are now gone. What I forgot to mention is that I have another mechanism `AddView` that is creating 2 runtime classes and putting those into a tabbed document view. This time, I've been using `GetTabControl()` to make it pretty, but this also suffers from the same issue, the scroll arrows are now present.

This is what the code looks like that creates the 2 new tabs:

```
Above this code is the constructor/destructor/headers, nothing else.

IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CTrackView, CTabView)

void CTrackView::OnInitialUpdate()
{

    // add document views   
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CTrainView), AfxStringID(IDS_TRAIN));
    AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CStationView), AfxStringID(IDS_STATION));
    GetTabControl().EnableTabSwap(TRUE);
    GetTabControl().SetLocation(CMFCBaseTabCtrl::Location::LOCATION_BOTTOM);
    GetTabControl().ModifyTabStyle(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D);
    GetTabControl().SetActiveTabBoldFont(TRUE);

    CTabView::OnInitialUpdate();
    
}
```

I have tried to comment out `CTabView::OnInitialUpdate();` but I know it won't and didn't affect the arrows. I done some searching on the control and I don't see any examples to remove the arrows, I assume another override is in order. I will follow the method shown in the other example, I am looking to see if it can be fixed similar to what has been shown.

Do these share the same `CMFCTabCtrl` mechanism or is this something different?

## Update 2:

The OutputWnd.cpp that the MFC wizard creates has the same issue now that I've modified the tab control, I can't find the right pointer to fix the issue where `&tabCtrl()`is an unknown identifier.  EDIT: This was the issue, I found the fix, see update 3 to see the resolution.

```
int COutputWnd::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    if (CDockablePane::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
        return -1;

    CRect rectDummy;
    rectDummy.SetRectEmpty();

    // Create User Define tab style:
    int UserTabStyle = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("UserTabStyle"), 0); //Get value from registry
    // If the key doesn't exist, UserTableStyle will be 0 or FALSE;

    if (UserTabStyle != FALSE && UserTabStyle <= 8) { // User selected tab style type

        int EnumUserTabStyle = UserTabStyle - 1; // Fix enum if key doesn't exist.

        if (!m_wndTabs.Create(static_cast<CMFCTabCtrl::Style>(EnumUserTabStyle), rectDummy, this, 1))
        {
            TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
            return -1;      // fail to create
        }
    }
    else { // Default tabs style if Reg key does not exist i.e. new install/program reset
        
        if (!m_wndTabs.Create(CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_FLAT, rectDummy, this, 1))
            {
                TRACE0("Failed to create output tab window\n");
                return -1;      // fail to create
            }
    }

    // Nicely hack to access protected member
    class CMFCTabCtrlEx : public CMFCTabCtrl
    {
    public:
        void SetDisableScroll() { m_bScroll = FALSE; }
    };

    // One-Liner to Disable navigation control
    ((CMFCTabCtrlEx*)&tabCtrl())->SetDisableScroll();

    // Create output panes:
    const DWORD dwStyle = LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_HSCROLL | WS_VSCROLL | WS_BORDER;

    if (!m_wndOutputBuild.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 2) ||
        !m_wndOutputDebug.Create(dwStyle, rectDummy, &m_wndTabs, 3))
    {
        TRACE0("Failed to create output windows\n");
        return -1;      // fail to create
    }   

    UpdateFonts();

    CString strTabName;
    BOOL bNameValid;

    //Attach list windows to tab:
    bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_STATUS_TAB);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputBuild, strTabName, (UINT)0);

    bNameValid = strTabName.LoadString(IDS_DEBUG_TAB);
    ASSERT(bNameValid);
    m_wndTabs.AddTab(&m_wndOutputDebug, strTabName, (UINT)1);

    int EnableDebugTab = AfxGetApp()->GetProfileInt(_T("Settings"), _T("EnableDebugTab"), 0); //Get value from registry
    if (EnableDebugTab == FALSE)
    {
        OnOutputtabsDebug(); //Check to see if it should be enabled
    }

    return 0;
}
```

## Update 3:

I found the answer to my unknown identifier, I was trying to call a function that didn't exist. Reformed as such and it works as expected:

```
// Nicely hack to access protected member
class CMFCTabCtrlEx : public CMFCTabCtrl
{
public:
    void SetDisableScroll() { m_bScroll = FALSE; }
};

// One-Liner to Disable navigation control
((CMFCTabCtrlEx*)&m_wndTabs)->SetDisableScroll();
```

Comment: What type is this? Can you provide some more information? Is this the [TabbedView](https://github.com/microsoft/VCSamples/tree/master/VC2010Samples/MFC/Visual%20C%2B%2B%202008%20Feature%20Pack/TabbedView) sample?

Comment: Question, is your application derivev from CWinApp or CWinAppEx?

Comment: Defined as Win32 in properties but shows this in the message map: BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CApplication, CWinAppEx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remembered I solved this in the past with an One-liner.
Here a solution (hack) to direct access the m_bScroll Variable in your CTrackView::::OnCreate() function. OnInitialUpdate() comes too late as dxiv explained.

```
int void CTrackView::::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
   if (CTabView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
     return -1;

     // add document views   
     AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CTrainView), AfxStringID(IDS_TRAIN));
     AddView(RUNTIME_CLASS(CStationView), AfxStringID(IDS_STATION));
     :
     :
   
     // Nicely hack to access protected member
     class CMFCTabCtrlEx : public CMFCTabCtrl
     {
       public:
         void SetDisableScroll() { m_bScroll = FALSE; }
     };

     // One-Liner to Disable navigation control
     ((CMFCTabCtrlEx*)&GetTabControl())->SetDisableScroll();

 }
```

Comment: Looks like that will do it, but I have one unknown identifier which is `&tabCtrl`. Everything else plugs right in, it doesn't seem unique to your code, is there a header that needs to be in place that I may not have included?

Comment: tabCtrl  was a simple variable returned  by GetTabContol().  Ok, updated the code.

Comment: I saw the edit come in, worked perfect...I was thinking if I could sub it in, but you changed it before I got there....changing it from `&tabCtrl` to `&GetTabControl()` is exactly what I needed. Why can't MS make things easy! Thanks Tom Tom! Chris

Answer (score 3):

There is no public, documented API to hide those navigation buttons. However, digging into the MFC sources finds that:

- the arrows are `CMFCTabButton m_btnScrollLeft, m_btnScrollRight, m_btnScrollFirst, m_btnScrollLast;` in `CMFCTabCtrl`;
- they are created in `CMFCTabCtrl::OnCreate` whenever `CMFCTabCtrl::m_bScroll` is `TRUE`;
- `CMFCTabCtrl::m_bScroll` is set to `TRUE` in `CMFCTabCtrl::Create` if any of the styles `STYLE_FLAT`, `STYLE_FLAT_SHARED_HORZ_SCROLL`, `STYLE_3D_SCROLLED`, `STYLE_3D_ONENOTE`, `STYLE_3D_VS2005`, or `STYLE_3D_ROUNDED_SCROLL` is used.

With that insight, the navigation buttons can be turned off in a couple of ways.

- By the book: create the `CMFCTabCtrl` without any of the styles that enable those buttons, which leaves only `STYLE_3D` available. That loses the navigation buttons, indeed, but the styling of the tab control also becomes different, and the tabs themselves display as small rectangles rather than trapezoids.
- Undocumented: override the `CMFCTabCtrl::m_bScroll` and set it to `FALSE` before the tab window gets created. For example, derive a class `CMyTabCtrl` to clear `m_bScroll`.

  ```
  class CMyTabCtrl : public CMFCTabCtrl
  {
  protected:
    BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT &cs) override
    {
      m_bScroll = FALSE;
      return CMFCTabCtrl::PreCreateWindow(cs);
    }
  };
  ```

  Then instantiate the control as `CMyTabCtrl m_wndTabs;` instead of `CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTabs;`.

Comment: I had a gut feeling that one of those `STYLE_<make it look like it did DECADES ago>` flags were part of the equation. Thanks for the complete summary.

Comment: I converted to your class and reassigned the object instantiation. I am running into C4430 (this is older code, but the OutputWnd.h was created using VS2017). I think once I solve that issue, I'll be ok. Thanks for that detailed information, it does explain a lot of why my search results were dry. Thanks again.

Comment: @Kittmaster C4430 suggests a misplaced declaration or include sequence. The definition of the class `CMyTabCtrl` must be available at the point where `CMyTabCtrl m_wndTabs;` is declared. In a wizard-generated project, you could define `CMyTabCtrl` in `OutputWnd.h` just before the `COutputWnd` class that has `CMyTabCtrl m_wndTabs;` as a member.

Comment: I was able to resolve it by moving it above...I figured that out shortly prior to you posting this, so thank you for that! I have updated the original question, I was wondering if you could have a look an possibly comment? TY.

Comment: @Kittmaster That's a very different scenario. `CTabView::OnInitialUpdate` comes too late to be useful, since you must intercept the creation of the tab control. You could probably derive a `class CMyTabView : public CTabView` to handle `WM_CREATE`, and in `CMyTabView::OnCreate` copy the MFC code from `CTabView::OnCreate` (in `afxTabView.cpp`) but change the style passed to `m_wndTabs.Create` to just `CMFCTabCtrl::STYLE_3D`. Or completely rewrite your own `class CMyTabView : public CView` and replace the member `CMFCTabCtrl m_wndTabs;` with `CMyTabCtrl m_wndTabs;`.

Comment: I did find someone who had the same issue, to me, it seems like some assumptions where made, so I'd like to adapt it, but his functions are `OnCreate` and will not line up to my function type. What are your thoughts on his info: https://www.penguinstew.ca/Writings/30/Programming/How-To/MFC/Have%20a%20CTabView%20without%20Arrow%20Buttons

Comment: @Kittmaster The `CTabbedInfoView` there is what I called `CMyTabView` in my previous comment. You need to derive your own class and write your own `OnCreate` based on the MFC code but create `m_wndTabs` with a different style that does not cause the navigation buttons to be included.